# Getting Album Name with Song Title and Artist

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I m trying to get an album information/album cover of an artist in my program.
i m trying to do it through (example: madonna/frozen);

```
String urlToRead = "http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=artist:madonna+recording:frozen";
```

to get the album information and cover foto also if its possiable information about the artist.
what i habe been trying until now;

```
String urlToRead = "http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=artist:madonna+recording:frozen";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String result = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urlToRead);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String  out = result;
```

But the output is a huge xml file in string format which full of information that doesnt really match what i want.(so many random albums which Madonna s song frozen in it)
Is there any other simple way to do it ? If not how could i get the exactly information from my output ?
Any tipps?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, if you haven't already: https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/Search

That contains a list of fields that search fields you can use to narrow down your search result, including a LIMIT field if you only wish to retrieve one result.

As for the album art - that's handled by a separate API - https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Cover_Art_Archive/API - you can use their Java bindings in your program to fetch the album covers ( https://github.com/lastfm/coverartarchive-api )